# Can a set (as a candidate to be a vector space) be shown to be closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication in one step?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

That is to say, is showing that $(\alpha \textbf{v} + \beta \textbf{w} \in V)\, \forall \, \textbf{v}, \textbf{w} \in V$ for a vector space $V$ completely equivalent to showing both that $(\textbf{v} + \textbf{w} \in V) \, \forall \, \textbf{v}, \textbf{w} \in V$ *and* that $(\alpha \textbf{v} \in V)\, \forall \, \textbf{v} \in V, \alpha \in F = \mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The latter two statements are specialisations of the first statement; the first statement being true implies that they are true, if you set $(\alpha = \beta = 1)$ and then $(\beta = 0)$ while $(\alpha)$ is allowed to take on an arbitrary value.

The truth of the first statement is implied from the latter two statements with "$(\alpha \textbf{v})$ and $(\beta \textbf{w})$ are in $V$" as an intermediate logical step.